# How to let conda know that I have spyder already?

Tags: python, conda, spyder

I installed spyder using their standalone installer. Then I installed miniconda because I don't want the bundle of packages that come with anaconda. But when I use the base environment of conda, it doesn't show spyder. I understand that this is supposed to happen. So how do I let conda know that I have spyder installed already? Do install it again? Won't I have 2 copies of spyder in that case?

Comment: read up on `spyder-kernels`

Comment: I didn't bother tinkering I just uninstalled it and insalled anaconda nav.